# Can I setup kubernetes cluster using kubeadm on ubuntu machines inside a office LAN

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I was looking at [this url](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/pick-right-solution/#universal).

It says-"If you already have a way to configure hosting resources, use `kubeadm` to easily bring up a cluster with a single command per machine."

What do you mean by "If you already have a way to configure hosting resources"?

If I have a few Ubuntu machines within my office LAN can I setup Kubernetes cluster on them using `kubeadm`?

Comment: Yes, I was just able to install the cluster on CentOS with Kubeadm in an office network. Kubeadm is an universal tools for bare metals, I think. Just mind the proxy settings if you are working behind a corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that you already have a way of installing an OS on these machines, booting them, assigning IPs on your LAN and so. If you can SSH into your nodes to be you are ready!

Follow the [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) carefully and you will have a demo cluster in no time.